# GridView doesn't scroll

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

i'm developping an android application based on a Tabbar navigation model.
one of the views of my application contains a "3 columns" gridview , that contains 10 elements , i can only see 9 elements , i can't scroll.

this is my code :

**MoreFragment.java**

```
public class MoreFragment extends Fragment implements
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

static final String EXTRA_MAP = "map";

static final LauncherIcon[] ICONS = {
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.casino, "Casino", "casino.png"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.cinema, "Cinema", "cinema.png"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.quad, "Quad", "quad.png"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.tennis, "Tennis", "tennis.png"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.golf, "Golf", "golf.png"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.club, "Club", "club.png"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.jazz, "Jazz Bar", "jazz.jpg"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.pool, "Pool", "pool.png"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.ic_7, "Map" ,"ic_7.png"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.drawable.fono,"Contact" ,"fono.png")


};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, null);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    gridview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    FragmentManager fm2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft2 = fm2.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            fragment = new Generic_SimplePage(getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_titles).getResourceId(0,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_desc).getResourceId(0,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_backgrounds).getResourceId(0,-1) );
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Generic_SimplePage(getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_titles).getResourceId(1,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_desc).getResourceId(1,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_backgrounds).getResourceId(1,-1) );
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Generic_SimplePage(getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_titles).getResourceId(2,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_desc).getResourceId(2,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_backgrounds).getResourceId(2,-1) );
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Generic_SimplePage(getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_titles).getResourceId(3,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_desc).getResourceId(3,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_backgrounds).getResourceId(3,-1) );
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Generic_SimplePage(getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_titles).getResourceId(4,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_desc).getResourceId(4,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_backgrounds).getResourceId(4,-1) );
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new Generic_SimplePage(getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_titles).getResourceId(5,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_desc).getResourceId(5,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_backgrounds).getResourceId(5,-1) );
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new Generic_SimplePage(getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_titles).getResourceId(6,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_desc).getResourceId(6,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_backgrounds).getResourceId(6,-1) );
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new Generic_SimplePage(getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_titles).getResourceId(7,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_desc).getResourceId(7,-1),getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.entertainement_backgrounds).getResourceId(7,-1) );
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new MapFragment();
            break;
        case 9 : 
        fragment = new ContactFragment();
            break;
    default:
        break;

    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        ft2.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
        ft2.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
        ft2.commit();

    }

}

static class LauncherIcon {
    final String text;
    final int imgId;
    final String map;

    public LauncherIcon(int imgId, String text, String map) {
        super();
        this.imgId = imgId;
        this.text = text;
        this.map = map;
    }

}

static class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ICONS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public LauncherIcon getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView icon;
        public TextView text;
    }

    // Create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_icon, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.dashboard_icon_text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.dashboard_icon_img);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.icon.setImageResource(ICONS[position].imgId);
        holder.text.setText(ICONS[position].text);

        return v;
    }
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  android:weightSum="1.0"
   >
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radiogroup"
         >
    </FrameLayout>

  <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/navbar_background"
  >
  <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPres"
        style="@style/navbar_button"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_presselector"
        android:text="Presentation"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRooms"
        style="@style/navbar_button"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_roomsselector"
        android:text="Rooms"
    />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRestaurants"
        style="@style/navbar_button"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_restaurantsselector"
        android:text="Restaurants"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btnReservation"
        style="@style/navbar_button"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_reservationselector"
        android:text="Reservation"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btnMore"
        style="@style/navbar_button"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_moreselector"
        android:text="More"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    />
 </RadioGroup>



 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/floatingmenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/laysemitransparentwithborders"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ff999999"
    />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**gridview.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/b_ground6">

 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:columnWidth="50px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10.0dip"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10.0dip"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    style="@style/dashboard"
    />


   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wants the grid view why are you setting the onTouchListener?

I think the problem is here, try to comment thi piece of code and test

```
// Hack to disable GridView scrolling
    gridview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
        }
    });
```

Comment: perfect ! i did'nt mention that !